# Trying to get all elements after first match using linq

Tags: c#, linq

How do I retrieve all elements after the first one not starting with a `"-"` using linq?

```
var arr = new[] {"-s1", "-s2", "va", "-s3", "va2", "va3"};
var allElementsAfterVA = from a in arr where ???? select a;
```

I want `allElementsAfterVA` to be `"-s3", "va2", "va3"`

Comment: Why do you want to use linq here? It doesn't know or care what order your items are in if it's a simple string array

Comment: Do you mean the first one NOT starting with a "-"?

Comment: @MatteS: Okay - Now your question makes more sense :)

Comment: Yup, missed a *not*, sorry bout that =)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To find all of the arguments after the first that does NOT start with "-", you can do:

```
var elementsAfterFirstNonDash = arr.SkipWhile(i => i[0] != '-').Skip(1);
```

This finds "va", then skips it via Skip(1).  The rest of the arguments will be returned.

Comment: That seems like a solution only for this test case. Does not seem like you can use this on any data set...

Comment: It still seems like a test data specific solution. Maybe something a little more generic. Or is the question to vague to create a generic solution?

Comment: Yes, the solution seems to only be for this test case. As an example, I want to get all elements after the first one *not* starting with "-"...

Comment: @MatteS: I just rewrote this after your question edit.  I believe it's exactly what you want, now.

Comment: @MatteS. Next time, please be more specific as to what you want, as the original question made it very difficult. **Good answer @Reed**

Comment: @MatteS: Does this do what you're after now?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please be more clear? 
If I understood correctly, the first one starting with a "-" is "-s1", so the elements after this would be "-s2", "va", "-s3", "va2", "va3" and not "-s3", "va2", "va3"

Comment: Sorry, I missed a *not* there... I meant to say "after the first one not starting with a "-""..

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get the question from your text, but looking at the example: Did you look at SkipWhile()? Seems to be related/useful?

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.Where((n, i) => i > 0 && n.StartsWith("-"))
```

yields

```
-s2 -s3
```

Is this what you meant?